# why can't it print response after making a request to an api/url?

Tags: python, api

I just found the bestbuyCA api by inspecting the xhr.

```
 aboveurl = 'https://www.bestbuy.ca/ecomm-api/availability/products?accept=application%2Fvnd.bestbuy.simpleproduct.v1%2Bjson&accept-language=en-CA&skus=14962185'
```

I've tried:：

```
  response= requests.get(aboveurl)
  print(response.text)
```

//

```
  r = requests.get(url).json()
  print(r)
```

When I run my code in vsc, it starts and keeps running but it will not display anything.

Comment: Just from having a quick look it doesn't look like your URL is in a string
aboveurl = ''

Comment: sorry it was a typo.

Comment: Probably you need to add HTTP headers in your request.

Comment: thank you, is there a documentation that I can read that will help me understand things like this like why it requries a header and what the api is looking for when I make the query

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a header to your request to get the request result:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
aboveurl = "https://www.bestbuy.ca/ecomm-api/availability/products?accept=application%2Fvnd.bestbuy.simpleproduct.v1%2Bjson&accept-language=en-CA&skus=14962185"
html = requests.get(aboveurl,headers=headers)
print(f'requrest code: {html.status_code}\n request text: {html.text}')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there any recommended documentation that I can read for explaining this?

Comment: yeah, u can read the official [docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Comment: Thank you, sorry to bother you again. I tried to convert "html" to json with html.json but it gave me an error code " json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)". Is there a way to convert the response"html" to json? "html" is <class 'requests.models.Response'>, shouldn't it contain json?

Comment: Hi, again I am able to solve it by using "decoded_data = html.text.encode().decode('utf-8-sig')
data = json.loads(decoded_data)"

Comment: That's great ^^